# Django qs1.difference(qs2, qs3) not supported by backend

Tags: django, django-queryset

I need to check a table from a remote db and update another table in my db. The models have same fields but checking with difference method will return an error:

> qs1 get the data from one postgresql db
>
> qs2 get the data from one mysql db

```
qs1 = (Local.objects
            .values_list('ref')
)
qs2 = (Remote.objects
            .filter()
            .values_list('ref'))

>>> qs1.difference(qs1, qs2)
```

> DatabaseError: intersection not supported on this database backend.

Comment: Yes, so what is your question?

Comment: what am I doing wrong? I cannot get the difference, I get this error.

Comment: As the error states, it seems you're using a backend that is not compatible with this feature (I guess you're not using PostgreSQL).
`difference()` method is new in Django 1.11 so maybe there are other methods to do what you want to do, that will work with your backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
check = Qs1.objects.all()
prg=[]
[prg.append(x.ref) for x in check]
difference = (Qs2.objects
        .exclude(ref__in=prg)
        .values()
)
```

Maybe it's not elegant, but it just works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you think your code is doind.

qs1 looks for a model *Local* in your default Databasengine. And qs2 looks for a model *Remote* also in your default Databasengine.

What you might want to do is defining a second Database in your **settings.py** 
naming it for Instance "remote" and then modify your q2 as follows :

```
qs2 = (Remote.objects.using("remote").filter().values_list('ref'))
```

This tells django that it shall contact your remote Database not your Local one.

Lemme know wether this helps or not.